# VSCode go extension: could not import error

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I'm currently learning golang, I'm using windows

I've installed VSCode's `Go` extension.

When I hover over new package added by `goimports` in VSCode, I get the error

```
could not import io/ioutil (cannot find package "io/ioutil" in any of 
    C:\Users\<username>\go\src\io\ioutil (from $GOROOT)
    C\src\io\ioutil (from $GOPATH)
    \Users\<username>\go\src\io\ioutil (from $GOPATH))compiler
```

I have installed go in `C:\Users\<username>\go`. When I check the directory `C:\Users\<username>\go\src\io\ioutil` it exists(the `ioutil.go` file is present as well).

It's a package in go's standard library, yet it is not detected by the extension. I have to reload VSCode for it to work. Also when I compile the code using `go build` or `go run` command, the code compiles.

Comment: Install Go where the instalation guide tells you to do.

Answer (score 2):

You should install Go somewhere else than `C:\Users\<username>\go` as that is also default `GOPATH`. Having `GOPATH` (a directory where your user modules are installed) in same place as `GOROOT` (a directory where Go itself is installed) will cause a lot of different problems and confuse many tools.

Either completely remove current installation and re-install Go somewhere else (recommended) or point your `GOPATH` somewhere else.